# How to arrive at the $n^{th}$ term of the following progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following series:

$T_{1} = m$
$T_{2} = 3m + 2$
$T_{2} = 9m + 8$
$T_{n} = 3T_{n-1} + 2$  , where $m$ is an integer

How do you arrive at the $n^{th}$ term as a function of $n$ and $m$?

---

The first term of $T_{n}$ its clearly $3^{n}m$, but the tricky part is figuring out the second term which has no $m$. It kind of approximates to a geometric progression as the number gets bigger, as addition of $2$ becomes less and less significant. But apart from that the progression is jumpy because of the addition of $2$ at every increment.

Comment: Can you add some more context to the body of your question? Where did this question arise, what attempts have you made to solve it, etc.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut this question was there in one of the old puzzle books, I tried solving it but it became a huge mess, so I posted it here.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible for you to add a bit more detail about what you tried? If it's messy, you don't need to give all the details, but it will help people give an answer that helps you get unstuck.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I'm a noob in mathematics, so only I tried to solve puzzles. I basically did some algebra of multiplying with 3 and adding 2 repeatedly to find a pattern. But I couldn't find any pattern

Comment: @MrGreenGold Write it as $\,T_n+1=3(T_{n-1}+1)\,$ and notice that $\,T_n+1\,$ must be a geometric progression.

Comment: @dxiv superb..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a guess, we can calculate a few terms:
\begin{align*}
T_1&=m\\
T_2&=3m+2\\
T_3&=9m+8\\
T_4&=27m+26\\
T_5&=81m+80.
\end{align*}
So, we can make a guess that the unit term is one less than the coefficient of $m$. In other words, we expect
$$T_n+1=3^{n-1}(m+1).$$
See if you can show this using the recursion (by *induction*) -- show that it's true for $n=1$, and then show that if it's true for $n$ it's also true for $n+1$.

Comment: Here's the second part posted as a different question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4213157/933694

Comment: It should be $T_n=3^{n-1}(m+1)-1$